# How to add primary key to View?

Tags: postgresql

I have a view and want to make one attribute a primary key.

```
CREATE VIEW filedata_view
AS SELECT num PRIMARY KEY, id, ST_TRANSFORM(the_geom,900913) AS the_geom
FROM filedata
```

But get a error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PRIMARY"
LINE 2: AS SELECT num PRIMARY KEY, id, ST_TRANSFORM(the_geom,900913)...
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Views in Postgresql can't have primary keys.

you are basically on wrong way creating constraint on a View, constraints should be created on tables, but some DBMSes do support adding constraints on Views like oracle with this syntax:

```
ALTER VIEW VIEW_NAME ADD PRIMARY KEY PK_VIEW_NAME DISABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

[Oracle Doc For Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm)

> You can specify only unique, primary key, and foreign key constraints on views, and they are supported only in DISABLE NOVALIDATE mode.

so they only support it for compatibility, if you want to have a primary key to stop insertion of duplicate data in column **num** in **filedata** table, you should do it by altering the **filedata** table and add a primary key on it or by creating your table with primary key on column **num** from the start.

Comment: @KliverMax: from the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createview.html): _You can get the effect of an updatable view by creating rules that rewrite inserts, etc. on the view into appropriate actions on other tables._ Also googling for _postgresql updatable views_ should give you plenty of advice.

Comment: Is there any online reference about this question?

Comment: Ack!  This is a significant gotcha for CPAN's `Rose::DB::Object`, where setting `include_views => 1` should seem to create objects for the views, but it doesn't because the default `require_primary_key => 1` setting excludes them.

Answer (score 14):

Postgresql doesn't support constraints on views. Other DBMSes (eg Oracle) do support this but Postgresql doesn't.

Comment: I prefer this answer over the accepted one because it provides a comparison to other DBMSes.  I find it fascinating that Oracle can provide this feature.